# Why do I have a segfault when using cmp instruction?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64

I am using YASM on Linux x86_64.

I am following an introduction to assembly language on the internet. I've covered basic data types. Now I'm diving into loops contruction. Good, but my first attempt is a failure. This code segfault around the use of the `cmd` instruction:

```
    segment .data
a       dd  0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04
b       dd  0x03,0x03,0x03,0x03
product dd  0x00

    segment .text
    global _start
_start:

    mov     rax,0

begin_while:
    cmp     rax,4
    jnl     end_while

    inc     rax
    jmp     begin_while
end_while:

    mov     rax,1
    xor     rbx,rbx
    int     0x80
```

But when I add those few lines just after the `_start` label, then it behaves as expected. i.e. no segfault.

```
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp,rsp
    sub     rsp,16
```

The book I am reading uses this construct from time to time. Not everytime. I understand that is has to do with the procedure to follow when calling a function. I guess it might be related to the libc runtime. Anyway, I do not understand why it's needed. So far with all the few simple programs I wrote (not so much) I never had to use it. Just today, now that I am using `jmp`.

Does someone have a good explanation about it?

Comment: Works fine here. Learn to use a debugger, and if you need further help, show us where the fault happens.

Comment: Make sure your file does not contain any stray non-ASCII control characters from wherever you copied it from and make sure you don't have mixed line endings in  your file  (e.g. `CRLF`, etc.). What editor are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are using the `x86` interrupt call

```
int     0x80
```

which should be changed to

```
syscall
```

for `x86_64`. You are relying on `x86` compatibility while using `64-bit` registers. As pointed out by Jester, your code will compile and run without error on `x86_64`. (I have confirmed it both ways without error on AMD64 Linux) However, the extent to which this is true for all platforms is unclear.

In writing x86_64 code, should also change:

```
mov     rax,1
```

to

```
mov     rax, 0x3c  ; 60 decimal
```

to setup the proper `x86_64` exit syscall instead of relying on `x86` compatibility. (in x86_64, the syscall number `1` is `__NR_write 1`, see: `/usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h` compared to `/usr/include/asm/unistd_32.h`)

Comment: That's not the reason, the 32 bit compatibility interface is still available. OP's code, while not recommended, does exit normally. Unless he has a special kernel with the interface disabled.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Clarified in answer. It still **should** be fixed, but not **must** be fixed for a clean `x86_64` exit.

Comment: Yes it should be fixed, but I doubt your answer helps with the actual problem (whatever it may be). It does run fine here as-is.

Comment: Well, you are correct again. It seems we need more info from the OP. Will update answer once again.